# Finding function from its properties

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Find function $z=z(x,y)$ such that:

$$\begin{cases}
z(x,0)=x, \\
z(0,y)=y^2, \\
\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x \, \partial y}=x+y \\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd equation, which may be rewritten more properly as:

$$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x \partial y} = x+y,$$

is a second order PDE for $z$. Then, by integrating w.r.t. $x$ and $y$ it yields:

$$ z_y = \frac{x^2}{2} + xy + f(y) \Rightarrow z = \frac{1}{2}(x^2y+xy^2) + G(x)+F(y).$$

Apply now the "boundary" conditions to solve for the arbitrary functions $G$ and $F$. This leads to:

$$x = G(x) + F(0), \quad  y = G(0) + F(y),$$

and then a solution is $G(x) = x, \ G(y) = y$.

I hope this is useful to you.

Cheers!